# How can you add additional values to a URL directory in Swift?

Tags: swift, url

I want to create a GUI which displays folders in different colors. I dont know how to store a color value to a directory. I already tried URL Extended Attributes but these one are only stored locally and iCloud strips them aways for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You have to add #s at the end of your extended name. This ensures that it will be synched.

S: XATTR_FLAG_SYNCABLE, which ensures the xattr is preserved even during syncing. Default behaviour is for xattrs to be stripped during syncing, to minimise the amount of data to be transferred, but this will override that default.

You can read more about it here :
https://eclecticlight.co/2020/03/18/which-extended-attributes-does-icloud-preserve-and-which-get-stripped/